# how to get inner text of message from web page?

Tags: excel, vba, ui-automation

I'm using below code to intract with the POP-Up/Message from webpage.

```
    hWND = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Message from webpage")
    hWND <> 0 Then childHWND = FindWindowEx(hWND, ByVal 0&, "Button", "OK")
    If childHWND <> 0 Then SendMessage childHWND, BM_CLICK, 0, 0
```

The POP up displays a value, such as "CGPA :  10", I wish to save that text ("CGPA :  10") in a variable.

I'm coding in VBA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751400/get-the-text-within-a-dialog-box

Comment: I'm not expert in coding. it would be really helpful if you cound explain it. or share the example.

Comment: I'm not proficient in using API calls - the question I linked has the approach to take if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Might suggest getting something either like Selnium or Playwright that will drive and test web based application.  The main problem i'm seeing you are doing FindwindowEx and the native Win32 api's are for Win32 native apps and not web applications as Selenium and Playwright are.   Either of them would be the right way to go.

Comment: If it's an `alert()` then it would be a "regular" dialog, not a "pop-over" HTML thing?